# How to simulate mouseMovement in-game?

Tags: python, directx, mouseevent, mouse, mousemove

I've just started learning python few days ago and I'd like to know how to simulate mouse movements inside games that have forced mouse coordinates.
directx environments?

I've currently tested pyautogui, ctypes, wxpython. I've also tried using directpython11 but I've had trouble installing it, ton of dll errors.

Can't find any topics helping with this in google, lots of pages on how to click or write in these kinds of cases but nothing about moving the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a perfect solution, it will require some extra stuff to run but its the shortest way.

Haven't found anyone who actually knows how to simulate mouse but decided to ask Sentdex for help and he recommended using vJoy to simulate controller.
So you need to simulate a controller instead of mouse by using a combination of vJoy(controller driver) and FreePIE(Input emulator).

After doing some research, for my purpose the best solution for moving on the  axis(x,y) is to bind controller (x,y) axis movements to keyboard shortcuts(E.g. W.A.S.D) and make the main script to press these shortcuts, if I'm looking in the wrong direction.

tl;dr Simulate controller. NEED: vJoy, FreePie

Answer (score 0):

Pyautogui is a great, beginner-friendly option that can handle basic mouse movements and clicking keys. If you also want to be able to "listen" for keyboard or mouse input, pyHook or pynput are potential options.

I recently wrote a two-part blog post discussing 1) game bot detection ([part I](http://www.zaxrosenberg.com/how-to-write-a-runescape-auto-clicker-with-python-part-i/)) and 2) showing an example bot written using pyautogui (among other tools) for game interaction ([part II](http://www.zaxrosenberg.com/how-to-write-a-runescape-autoclicker-with-python-part-ii/)). Hopefully those help get you started.

Comment: as I said, I've tried pyautoqui and it doesn't work since the coordinates are forced, it would require a module that would send mouse movement signals not coordinate movements. nice blog post tho.